# Expressing L-functions as Mellin transforms

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I often see the use of the integral representation
$$\sum_{n < N} \frac{a_n}{n^s} = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{(3)} \sum_{n} \frac{a_n}{n^s} \frac{N^s}{s} ds$$

Is it justified by a kind of application of the residue theorem? Where does this equality comes from?

Comment: It is the Perron's formula. There are some mistakes in this formulation; see the correct version here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula . However, it is a direct application of the residue theorem to the function $x^{s}/s$ and then extended to the case with Dirichlet series.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, $\int_{(3)} = \int_{3 - i\infty}^{3 + i\infty}$. This is standard notation in analytic number theory, which is the tag for this question, so I don't understand why you asked about this.